# Is there an Excel to remove information from columns, but to keep other rows untouched?

Tags: microsoft-excel

We have a large batch of data that we need to filter out using Excel.

"Column B" contains an Email address, with additional columns containing relevant and necessary information.

I know that you can use functions to figure out which entries appear in two columns (or appear in one, but not the other) and input that entry in a third column.

What we'd like to do is run a function like this - to find out which entries appear in Column B but don't, say, appear in Column C. However, we want to make sure that all the information in the row corresponding to the entry in Column B is kept the same.

i.e. let's say that in Column B in Row 231 has relevant information in Column G and H and it appears in Column C, so this one is OK. However, Row 232 in Column B doesn't appear in Column C, so will be removed.

Is it possible to do all of this, but ensure the other information isn't touched?

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected outcome? Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are referring to emails in your question. The cell value would be a string data type, you can use the below code to compare strings.

**Only Remove Cell Contents**

```
Sub stringCompareColumns()
    For checkRow = 1 To Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
            If StrComp(Range("B" & checkRow).Value, Range("C" & checkRow).Value) = 1 Then Range("B" & checkRow).Clear
    Next

End Sub
```

[image]

**Remove Entire Row**

```
Sub compareColumnsRemoveRow()
    For checkRow = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row To 2 Step -1
            If StrComp(Range("B" & checkRow).Value, Range("C" & checkRow).Value) = 1 Then Rows(checkRow).EntireRow.Delete
    Next

End Sub
```

[image]